# How to show text from jsons reposne in textview after a specified interval of time?

Tags: android

I have a textview in which I want to show text which I had got from server response in a specified interval of time and also when dataset comes to an end i want to again view from start in textview.How can I do that.

code:-

```
private CDealAppDatastorage item;
private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ArrayList<CDealAppDatastorage> s_oDataset;


try{
        String json;
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("dealcategory","DEALTEST");
        json = jsonObject.toString();
        Log.e(TAG,"Server Reqeust::-"+json);

        final String m_szTicker = "http://14.192.16.1555:8080/rest/json/metallica/getDealListsJSON?";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, m_szTicker,jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Server Response::"+response);
                try{

                    if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Transaction Successful")){
                        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// get Deal list in array from r
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {// loop for counting deals from server
                            JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// counting deal based on index
                            item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// creating object of DealAppdata storage
                            item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));// get deal name from response
                            s_oDataset.add(item);// add all items in ArrayList

                        }
                        int i;
                        for (i=0;i<s_oDataset.size();i++){
                            Log.e(TAG,"Data Size:"+i);

                            final int finalI = i;
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    CDealAppDatastorage m = s_oDataset.get(finalI);
                                    m_Text.setText(m.getM_szHeaderText());
                                }
                            },6000);

                        }

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());// creating object of Request queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);// add json Object request to request queue
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: please explain your question long

Comment: I have an array which I got from json response let suppose"Deal" that array has a parameter"dealName" which I fetch and want to show in textview after a specified interval of time.

Comment: see my ans below if this helps you pls upvote my ans

Answer (score 0):

replace this code while setting text in textview inside handler ,  if you want to change text in handler then you have to use runonuiThread for ui update

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m_Text.setText(m.getM_szHeaderText());
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code..it can show value in textview after 5sec

```
  Handler handler = new Handler(); 
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override 
      public void run() { 
           txtView.setText(your_text); 
      } 
   }, 5000);
```